# How to calculate Autocorrelation times (area under ACF)

Tags: correlation

I hope I am posting this in the correct forum.

I was told I can calculate the are under the autocorrelation function using the autocorellation coefficient.
I have been trying to find a source or a method to do that and I wasnt able to.

Does anyone have an advise or a ling to help me please?

Thank you in advance.